# Strange continuity near end of "The Fanatic"

Tags: continuity, the-fanatic

Near the end of "*The Fanatic*" there is some very strange continuity.

The stains on the shirt worn by one character keep changing from one shot to the next, sometimes small, sometimes large, sometimes tightly clustered, sometimes spread out.

I wondered if perhaps this was a dream or fantasy scene, with one pattern representing reality, but no that wasn't it at all.

This repeated bad continuity is very blatant, and it's difficult to imagine no one noticed it during production, much less during editing.
The rest of the film seems to be edited just fine.

And even if it were totally accidental, surely it wouldn't have been that difficult to "photoshop" the problem, especially as it occurs throughout the climax of the story.

But if it *was* deliberate, what was the point?